# Rails less/sass conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, less, summernote

I have a LESS-based rails application.
since I added [summernote html editor](https://github.com/summernote/summernote-rails), I had to add also SASS code to my project.
So I added these lines:

**Gemfile:**

```
gem 'font-awesome-rails'
gem 'summernote-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
```

**application.css:**

```
*= require font-awesome
*= require summernote
```

In local everything works fine.
When I commit the application to heroku I get the following error:

```
Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined variable: "$alert-padding".
   (in /tmp/build_xxx/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.1.0/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_alerts.scss:10)
```

I guess I miss the SASS variables, but have no idea how to add them without create any conflict with the LESS code.

============= EDIT =================
The precompilation is broken on the first sass variable it finds, in file `/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.1.0/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_alerts.scss`:

```
.alert {
  padding: $alert-padding;
```

I assume the precompiler does not have any SASS variable declared, and fails to precompile on the first place it finds any.

============= EDIT =================
I added to my `application.scss` the `@import` I understand I needed to have, now it looks like this:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap/variables";
@import "bootstrap/mixins";
@import "bootstrap";
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require custom_bootstrap/custom_bootstrap
 *= require custom
 *= require social-share-button

 *= require bootstrap-datetimepicker

 *= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
 *= require dataTables/src/demo_table_jui
 *= require pricing

 *= require jquery.fileupload-ui

 *= require font-awesome
 *= require social-buttons-3.css

 *= require summernote
 */
```

I definitely have `_variables.scss` included (I renamed it in order to be sure), and I see that `$alert-padding` is declared:

```
$alert-padding:               15px !default;
$alert-border-radius:         $border-radius-base !default;
$alert-link-font-weight:      bold !default;
```

**Still, I get this error!**

**PD** - 
I use the following command in order to check precompilation locally:

```
RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find installation instructions [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#a-ruby-on-rails).

I fail to see at least those:

- `application.css` should be `application.scss`
- `gem 'sass-rails'` in your Gemfile
- use the `import` statements accordingly and appropriately in your `application.scss`

Comment: I already have `gem 'sass-rails'` in my Gemfile. I renamed `application.css` to have `scss` extention, but I do not know how to convert its content to have sass style (i.e. `@import` instead of `*= require`).
I recognized that my problem is that the sass variables are not included, actually the precompilation is broken on the first variable it finds... but have no idea how to include their declaration!